# Can't change apiVersion of an deployed Ingress from extensions/v1beta1 to networking.k8s.io/v1

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

```
Current version: 
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.0", GitCommit:"af46c47ce925f4c4ad5cc8d1fca46c7b77d13b38", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-12-08T17:59:43Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.9", GitCommit:"9dd794e454ac32d97cde41ae10be801ae98f75df", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-03-18T01:00:06Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

kubectl version --short:
Client Version: v1.20.0
Server Version: v1.19.9
```

I have tried to change the apiVersion through `kubectl edit` command and save it and was getting below error message added up in the YAML file after saving the file:

> Warning: extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.14+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress

### Error Message:

```
ingresses.extensions "current-ingress" was not valid: <nil>: Invalid value: "The edited file failed validation":  [ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend): unknown >field "serviceName" in io.k8s.api.networking.v1.IngressBackend, >ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend): unknown >field "servicePort" in io.k8s.api.networking.v1.IngressBackend]
```

---

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: // hostname
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: location
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

[snippet here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtpYQ.png)

Above is the format it has for `serviceName` and `servicePort` in the YAML file, I think that's the right way to write `serviceName` and `servicePort` declaration. If not, guide me here.

Could anyone help me how we can change the apiVersion of an deployed Ingress.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I have tried to change the syntax as per the latest use: (service.name & service.port.number) through kubectl edit for an deployed ingress, however I could change it, and it's throwing this message "(Error: at least one of apiVersion, kind and name was changed)" and nothing changes when I check back. I don't have the YAML file to re-apply the changes(kubectl apply -f xxx.yml). Any way to implement the change. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, @Popopame, apoorva kamath I have went through with the answers on a previously posted question: How to convert all kubernetes ingress yaml to use API version networking.k8s.io/v1
I have doubt on this, I have got the yaml file with this command: kubectl get ingress <name_of_the_ingress> -o yaml  > ingress.yml 
I have modified apiversion, spec.port,spec.port.number as it required on new apiversion: networking.k8s.io/v1 and I have applied it through kubectl apply -f ingress.yml. The changes are reflected in annotations but the real apiVersion wasn't changed. Help me to understand

Comment: @apoorva kamath

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the warning, it's just to inform you about the available API versioning as per this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/94761#issuecomment-691982480).

For the error it seems like you're using an outdated format, which has changed with `networking.k8s.io/v1` as per this [PR](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/89778), so it should be `service.name` and `servic.port.number`.

Please refer to the [official Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource) for more information.

Comment: Hi @jakub-siemaszko, I have tried to change the syntax as per the latest use: (service.name & service.port.number) through kubectl edit for an deployed ingress, however I could change  it, and it's throwing this message "(Error: at least one of apiVersion, kind and name was changed)" and nothing changes when I check back.
I don't have the YAML file to re-apply the changes(kubectl apply -f xxx.yml). Any way to implement the change. Thank you!